# Excel VBA Adding 'paste special as value' icon to right click menu (cell context menu customization)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I wonder how to add new icon to right click menu using VBA code which will be the shortcut to **paste special as value** Excel functionality (which can be found in Excel 2010, but not in 2007). Adding icon itself isn't the problem, but is there generic method (not VBA macro) which could be associated with that icon ?

Below code which add icon associated with `ToggleCaseMacro` macro (which isn't defined here) :

```
Sub AddToCellMenu()
    Dim ContextMenu As CommandBar
    Dim MySubMenu As CommandBarControl

    ' Delete the controls first to avoid duplicates.
    Call DeleteFromCellMenu

    ' Set ContextMenu to the Cell context menu.
    Set ContextMenu = Application.CommandBars("Cell")

    ' Add one built-in button(Save = 3) to the Cell context menu.
    ContextMenu.Controls.Add Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=3, before:=1

    ' Add one custom button to the Cell context menu.
    With ContextMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, before:=2)
        .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "ToggleCaseMacro"
        .FaceId = 59
        .Caption = "Toggle Case Upper/Lower/Proper"
        .Tag = "My_Cell_Control_Tag"
    End With
End Sub
```

[MSDN page with above code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg469862.aspx#odc_xl_ta_CustomExcelContextMenus_AddControlsUsingVBACode)

Comment: Here you are: http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/right-click.htm

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add:

```
ContextMenu.Controls.Add Type:=msoControlButton, ID:=370, Before:=2
```